# Question on the inner product of wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

When taking the inner product of a wavefunction $\Psi$ with itself, denoting the inner product as $(\Psi,\Psi)$, since $$\Psi(x)=\int \psi(x)\vec{x}dx$$ letting $$\overline\Psi(x')=\int \overline\psi(x')\vec{x'} dx'$$ would $$(\Psi,\Psi)= \int \overline\psi(x')\psi(x)\delta(x'-x)dx'dx$$ or would the $dx'$ not be included? If I am wholly wrong, how would I go about representing $(\Psi,\Psi)$?

Comment: Could you please explain your integral representation of the time-dependent state? I have never seen such an expression.

Comment: I don't think any of these expressions are correct. The inner product between two wave functions is not a double integral.

Comment: Sorry Just realized that is wrong

Comment: @Charlie can you explain where I am wrong and how?

Comment: @NDewolf He probably meant something like:
$$| \psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \langle x | \psi \rangle |x\rangle \, dx$$
but in different notation.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis That is exactly what I meant, I just can't figure out dirac notation in MathJax

Comment: @DanielWaters A small nitpick: Since $\Psi$ is a vector in a Hilbert space $\mathbb{V}$, it doesn't *technically* depend on the eigenvalues $x$. The element $\Psi$ **is** the entire function in your space. And if want to recover specific values at some $x$, you apply the linear functional $\langle x|$, from which you get the classic $\langle x | \Psi \rangle = \psi(x)$.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis I'm new to Quantum, this is just a question I came across when going through a derivation and it confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you went from $(1)$ and $(2)$ to $(3)$. But, here is a nice trick. In our Hilbert Space $\mathbb{V}$, the eigenbasis $|x\rangle$ satisfies:
$$\hat{I} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x\rangle \langle x| \, dx$$
where $\hat{I}$ is the identity operator in $\mathbb{V}$. Thus,
$$\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = \langle \Psi | \hat{I} | \Psi\rangle = \langle \Psi| \int_{\mathbb{R}} | x \rangle \langle x | \, dx \ |\Psi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \langle \Psi | x \rangle \langle x|\Psi\rangle \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi^{*}(x) \psi(x) \, dx \Longrightarrow$$
$$\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\psi(x)|^2 \, dx$$
Note that this is the same as:
$$\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi^{*}(x') \psi(x) \delta(x-x') \, dx' \, dx $$
but it is completely unnecessary to do that. You could have also arrived at the latter result through the following route:
$$\left\langle \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x) |x\rangle \, dx \ | \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x') |x' \rangle \, dx' \right\rangle$$
By using the $-$ *linearity in the second argument and anti-linearity in the first* $-$ properties of the inner product, we get:
$$\left\langle \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x) |x\rangle \, dx \ | \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x') |x' \rangle \, dx' \right\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x') \left\langle \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x) | x \rangle \, dx \ | x' \right\rangle dx' = $$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x') \psi^{*}(x) \langle x | x\rangle' dx' dx = \langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi^{*}(x') \psi(x) \delta(x-x') \, dx' \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\psi(x)|^2 \, dx$$